# How do I select which fields to show in the result of a mongodb sort?

Tags: mongodb

In mongodb I want to find some documents in a collection according to property X, sort them by property Y, then only show property Z, ie. something like

```
db.getCollection('something')
.find({X: "blah"})
.sort({Y: -1})
.find({}, {Z: 1})
```

but mongo complains that

```
Error: TypeError: db.getCollection(...).find(...).sort(...).find is not a function
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Try `db.getCollection('something').find({X: "blah"},{Z:1}).sort({Y: -1});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is called `projection`. Full details [in the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/).

For example, in your case, it should look something like:

```
 db.getCollection('something')
    .find({ X: "blah" }, { Z: 1 }).
    .sort({ Y: -1 })
```

But if you're looking for something more advanced, you can also use [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/). Something like:

```
db.getCollection('something').aggregate([
    { $match: { X: "blah" }},
    { $sort: { Y: -1 }},
    { $project: { Z: 1 }}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

May be the problem is with using `two find()` function together.

If you only want to show `z` in your result then do like this

```
db.getCollection('something')
.find({X: "blah"},'-_id z')
.sort({Y: -1});
```

Comment: Indeed, you can't apparently do two `find`s -- so what could I do?  I could try `map` but then I don't know the syntax of the function I have to write, in particular I don't know how to access a property with spaces in it from a function, eg. `function(d) {return "d.some awkward property";}` returns just that string.

Comment: what do you want to do by using `second find()` ? do you want to show only `Z` on output